# Question about the Import tag inside a csproj file

Tags: c#, .net, csproj

Inside my project I have a csproj file where at the top of the file it says:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Grpc.Tools.2.31.0\build\Grpc.Tools.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Grpc.Tools.2.31.0\build\Grpc.Tools.props')" />
```

and at the bottom of the file:

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Grpc.Tools.2.31.0\build\Grpc.Tools.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Grpc.Tools.2.31.0\build\Grpc.Tools.props'))" />
  </Target>
```

I have a little bit of an issue here with this package that is being imported. It is not being recognized in fact it does not even appear in the references tab for the project. The error message shown inside the `ErrorText` Tag gets printed when trying to compile the project. When I comment those lines out and rebuild the project, then all works fine again. I tried to restore the nuget packages but I just get shown the message that all nuget packages are up to date.

My question is:

**Are the lines above inserted automatically for you or is there a possibility that someone could have written those lines manually inside the file?**

Comment: These lines are automatically added by the old-style MSBuild-based version of NuGet restore. It hasn't been necessary to do it this way for quite a long time now. Both of these blocks can be thrown in the bin and `PackageReference` should be used instead.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your answer! Would it be fair to say that this package is not being used inside my code since it only throws me the error for the nuget package? I have no other compile time errors related to this package.

Comment: From the package description this is used to add support for compiling `.proto` files, so just leaving it out might be problematic, unless there's some other way those files are getting processed. If you clean your project entirely, then rebuild it, and it still works, it's probably safe, but only a runtime test could make sure.